# Lazy load pages in PrestaShop?

Tags: module, lazy-loading, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

By default, pagination in PrestaShop is available in every product page (displaying up to 10 items per page).

But according to my project requirements, I need a lazy loading page (only 10 products need to displayed before trying to scroll down the page). Does PrestaShop have this feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible by default.

You have to create your own module or buy/use available product like:

1. [Masonry All Products](http://codecanyon.net/item/masonry-all-products/7892114)
2. [Infinite Scroll for Prestashop](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/292177-infinite-scroll-for-prestashop/)

**3. [Answer](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/292177-infinite-scroll-for-prestashop/page-7#entry2104517) by [thepsyntist](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/user/870005-thepsyntist/) from https://www.prestashop.com/forums/**

> [...]    I successfully implemented an infinite scroll module on
>   Prestashop 1.6.0.11 (A custom theme) and 1.6.1.0 (Default theme).    I
>   found this module on GitHub a couple of months ago and finally today I
>   got success implementing it. Hence I have no direct link for it or
>   know who created it. [Link to the module.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/c8a72247ck4xwy2/muinfinitescroll.rar)

If you'd like to load images the same way, there is [one another module](http://addons.prestashop.com/pl/front-office-funkcje-moduly-prestashop/18676-lazy-loading.html).

Comment: Infinite Scroll for Prestashop . weather this module works with presthshop 1.6.1 ?

Comment: Probably it'd be better to ask an author of `Masonry All Products` about compatibility with 1.6.1.0. I guess this is what you're looking for: http://prestashop.nlitewebs.com/index.php?fc=module&module=allproducts&controller=display

Comment: Check also: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/292177-infinite-scroll-for-prestashop/?p=2104517

Comment: finally i got a answer . this module helps me a lot . even easy to install .no need to change any place , "http://www.mediafire.com/download/c8a72247ck4xwy2/muinfinitescroll.rar"